# How is it possible to having accepted highly upvoted but 100% wrong answer? Is there anything can do instead of just commenting?

Tags: discussion

Question : [How to get last inserted row ID from wordpress database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576018/how-to-get-last-inserted-row-id-from-wordpress-database)

The accepted answer has **125 up votes** and just 2 down votes.....

But answer is 100% wrong according to [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_row). (I tested it too....)

> This function returns false if the row could not be inserted.
>   Otherwise, it returns the number of affected rows (which will always
>   be 1).

OP asked that "last inserted row", but answer returns the affected rows.....

1. How it possible having huge up votes for a wrong answer... I mean **125 up votes** and just 2 down votes............
2. Is there anything we can do just type a comment saying answer is wrong.....

Comment: Seriously? It is not as if you are new on the site.

Comment: Mind explaining _what_ exactly you think is wrong with the answer?

Comment: Even if the scenario that the OP talks about actually happened... that is not something meta can do anything about. Are we going to debate misunderstood answers now?

Comment: Quote from the linked documentation: *"After insert, the ID generated for the AUTO_INCREMENT column can be accessed with: $wpdb->insert_id"*.  Quote from answer: *"$lastid = $wpdb->insert_id;"*. It looks more like a certain I am the Most Stupid Person is 100% wrong.

Comment: OP is absolutely 1000% correct that the answer is wrong. The correct answer is ***don't use PHP***.

Answer (score 14):

Did you *read* the answer?

They're asking for the last inserted id.

> After insert, the ID generated for the AUTO_INCREMENT column can be accessed with:
>
> ```
> $wpdb->insert_id
> ```
>
> ([source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#INSERT_row))

That answer looks perfectly valid.