# I'm "in danger of being blocked from asking any more" and I asked questions which got correct answers but no upvotes

Tags: support, post-ban

I've got the "in danger of being blocked from asking any more" message and asked a question which got no upvotes, but a good answer which I accepted.

Does this bring my ability to ask questions down, even if it got no downvotes?

Comment: You deleted any negatively-scored posts, by any chance?

Comment: @MartinJames Yes I deleted some not well recieved Questions. I know this will still infuence my ability to ask questions. However this does not answer the question i asked. And i dont know why I got so many downvotes without any explanation. I want to be a working member of this community an all I get is unreasoned downvotes. This really starts to annoy me since I dont think that i ask bad questions.

Comment: Hey, please disregard the most stupid person. Almost no one here will downvote without reading your question, or downvote because you have low rep. However, it is true that people will downvote poorly researched questions, and that votes on meta have no effect on your reputation.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson do you have any evidence of that?  [no]

Comment: @Bolphgolph 'this does not answer the question i asked' yes, which is why I only commented.  'i dont know why I got so many downvotes without any explanation' SO volunteers have only a limited amount of time spare, so personalized downvote explanations on bad questions take time away from answering good questions.  'all I get is unreasoned downvotes' - well since you deleted those questions, we can't review them.  'I dont think that i ask bad questions' when it comes to voting, it doesn't matter what you think - it matter what the other users decide.  All this has been repeatedly gone over:(

Comment: @MartinJames Yes I know. I deleted them only at the beginning because I didn't want to lose my reputation. This was a really bad idea. I am now banned from asking questions because someone(I don't know who) has downvoted some of my old questions. I will try to answer questions in the future to get my ban lifted. Thank you for your advise. I will try to improve myself

Comment: Answering questions will not push you out of a question ban. Your best bet is go through your old questions and edit them into shape, and hope that you improve them enough so they attract one or two up-votes that way. But you'll need to be careful, since bringing additional attention to a bad question bring additional down-votes as well, so you'd better make sure you are working hard to improve your existing questions, where possible.

Comment: I don't think you are getting downvoted here without anyone reading. Your question is just something you could find the answer for by doing a bit of meta research, instead of asking the regulars for the answer. You have to understand, while it's the first time you ask about it, it's **far** from the first time we see it.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson: please do not make assertions you can't back up with solid evidence. Most of all, I am going to ask you to [re-read our guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), which includes: *assume good intentions*. This applies to how people vote just as much as any other activity.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Too much downvotes for https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364647/looking-for-transcript-of-jon-skeet-podcast ........... Let say it is Ok. I mean there can be more users they don't want written versions... But why this was closed as "unclear"... If this question was asked by high rep users, this question won't be closed as "unclear".... I know that my English is bad... But I think it is a clear question........ That's why I said people downvote, close, etc done by not because of the question... Sometimes it happens because of low rep.....

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson: perhaps it happened there because the post lacks any kind of motivation as to why there should be a written transcript, nor do you share your research.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought " unclear what you're asking" means question is not clear... I mean others can't understand the question.....(I believe that others can't understand the question and others can't understand why this question is asked are two things) Am I wrong?

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson: several people voted to close it as unclear; I can't read their minds for you, but take it as an indication that the language of your post not as clear as it could have been. You yourself have [misunderstood posts in the past](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363465/), others may too. But when multiple people reach for the same close reason, then that's an indication your question could have been better.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, questions with no up-votes may influence your ability to continue asking questions.

Not having down-votes is not enough to make a question "well received".

That your question received one or more answers is not relevant.

Comment: Your action pulled me out of the ban. I'm sorry that i accused you of intentonally downvote my questions. I didnt know that editing the question brings it to the frontpage again.

Comment: Unless your future questions get a lot better, you'll will get back into ban territory soon. Work on that. There is a reason for the lack of up-votes in your existing questions.

Comment: "a lot better" is perhaps a little strong. The questions as they are are not terrible. They're a bit... lacking in research. Quite basic questions that one should be able to work out with a proper backing knowledge of the technology being used and/or with proper study into what needs to be achieved.