# Looking for transcript of Jon Skeet podcast

Tags: support, podcast

We can find answers for [Thanks a million, Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362019/thanks-a-million-jon-skeet) from [Podcast #123 – Jon Skeet Wants You To Be a Feminist](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/14/podcast-123-jon-skeet-wants-you-to-be-a-feminist/?cb=1).

It is a podcast. Where can I find a transcript of the podcast (the answers part would be enough)?

I asked this because  some users are not going to listen to an hour for something which can read in five minutes.

Comment: While not an unreasonable request - not everyone can watch video, for various reasons - it's a very time intensive thing to do. In the olden days when Stack Overflow was built, it used to be that volunteers transcribed Jeff Atwood's and Joel Spolsky's podcasts but I think that hasn't been done for a long time now

Comment: Also note that although there are answers to a few questions on the podcast (which is audio only), that's not the *main* Q&A session which was recorded as video. I believe that'll be coming soon.

Comment: It's definitely not unclear, and not an unreasonable question. I'm not going to listen to an hour for something I can read in five minutes. I misunderstood the question, so I changed my close-vote into a reopen-vote (TBH I did not vote to close as unclear).

Comment: Aye, It would be helpful for those that are hearing impaired like ... me. There were some moments where I was not able to follow the conversation because I rely on lipreading (in combination with hearing aids) when communicating with others.