# Can I comment on an old answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, old-questions, comment-replies, old-answers

Can I comment below a very old answer (more than a year for example) requesting more details from the person who wrote the answer or someone else and can I expect a reply?

Comment: You can *ask* but a reply is not guaranteed.

Comment: thanks Paulie, I've got some down-votes, I don't know why, I did search before asking so I guess it's not a duplicate. where did I go wrong do you think?

Comment: You could consider putting a bounty on the original question. I believe this is one of the standard bounty reasons. Although in your case you'd lose most of your rep, and with it the ability to comment.

Comment: you are right but I think I'm going to do what @Tanner suggest in his answer by making another question with more details on my specific problem.

Comment: @ZSmain Not sure why this is downvoted, but I have seen many times most new users meta-questions are downvotes in meta.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I'm confused, at least they can comment where I did go wrong so I can fix my question

Comment: @ZSmain For en example, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364647/looking-for-transcript-of-jon-skeet-podcast had lot of downvotes at the beginning. Then a few of high rep users comment on the my question that they have no idea why it is downvoting...Those comments also are deleted now...  Then I start to recive upvotes....  If there is no such comments, I am sure most of votes will be downvotes

Comment: @ZSmain about downvotes - it is really not clear what you tried/asking if you done your research. Assuming you've done some research (saying that you did not would not be welcoming, right?) - so "Can I comment below a very old answer" clearly not asking about whether you can actually do that (as you see the way to comment and likely done so already) - is it asking about some political/moral/religious reasons why you should not post a comment? Indeed some people see that as the indication that you did not even tried - downvote is perfectly reasonable for such case..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov oh thanks, I think I get it now, the fact is, I wasn't wondering whether I can comment or not (I obviously can and there is no wrong with that) but I guess maybe because I miss phrased the question because I was wondering if still get a reply.
I thought It was important to ask this question, because I was afraid that people will down vote my new question and mark it as duplicate and in the other hand is it worth it to wait for a reply in comments on a very old question which the person who wrote the answer may not even be available.
Should I change the title of the question?

Comment: Of course. The idea of stackoverflow is to find answers, so I don’t see any problem in commenting on old threads, just because sth‘s been inactive or simply old, doesn’t make it dead/ done/ final.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the first comment states, yes you can but you aren't guaranteed a response.

The other option is to ask a new question that references the older question and answer, where you ask for the additional details. Try to add as much detail as to what the previous answer is lacking in order to get a good response.

Comment: The second solution depends a lot on the scale, mass and type of those additional  questions, thinking of the strive for less duplicates on this platform imo.

Answer (score 4):

You can click on the answerer's icon and see if they are still active, there will be a last seen time on the right hand side of the profile time. It looks like this...

[image]

If you have 50 rep then yes you can comment on any post, but even if the poster has been active recently they aren't forced to reply.

Comment: This is good information but doesn't actually address the question that was asked by OP.

Comment: I know there's a userscript that adds this underneath the username & rep everywhere. Unfortunately after switching browsers I don't have the link anymore.